# Call Apex/Visualforce page from external website

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a script which is hosted on visualforce page. This script should be called from external website.
Is it possible to all Apex/Visualforce page from external website without authentication? Using XHR call?

```
<html>
<script>
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Apex/visualforce page url",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script> 
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, this is 2018. It's time to stop supporting IE 6.

Comment: @Chaithra K N, remember to accept the answer if it proved useful, you have several posts with asnwers that have not been accepted. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You'll need to first set up a Site in Salesforce, enable that Visualforce page for the Site, add CORS settings so your external site will be allowed JavaScript access, and then everything should work. You can do a similar trick with an Apex class, using either the RestResource annotation or the webservice keyword. Make sure you validate your input carefully, for security reasons. It's generally not a good idea to do this; you really should consider calling back to your server, having your server authenticate as an integration user, so you can control security better.

Comment: I totally agree for the security reason, but we are just documenting possible options for calling sf resource from external site.If you have any code snippet for this can you paste? I tried adding site visualforce page in the xmlhttp.open method.

Comment: Also the site which is calling VF and site domain is different.
I was using below code to call VF page from XHR call.
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://demositechaithra-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/",false);
TestAPI.html:15 Failed to load https://demositechaithra-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: (anonymous) @ TestAPI.html:15 TestAPI.html:15 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://demositechaithra-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/'. at file:///C:/Users/ChaithraNagaraj/Desktop/TestAPI.html:15:10

Comment: @ChaithraKN Okay, so my answer was (partially) incorrect. You need to be authenticated in order to get CORS to work, and it only works with a [limited list of items](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm). So, ultimately, you'll need to go through your server anyways.